# Building .NET Core 2.1 app fails in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I've created an ASP.NET Core **2.1** app that I'm trying to deploy to *Google Cloud Platform*. It builds just fine using `dotnet build` locally.

I cannot build it through Google Cloud Shell, though. Running `dotnet --version` confirms the Google Cloud Shell has .NET Core *2.0* installed.

Running `gcloud app deploy` initiates a deployment of the app, but I receive a cryptic error from the log saying:

> Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:ad1b788a9b4cca75bb61eb523ef358ca059c4bd208fba15a10ccc6acab83f49a
>
> Step #0: No .deps.json file found for the app
>   Finished Step #0
>
> ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/aspnetcorebuild@sha256:ad1b788a9b4cca75bb61eb523ef358ca059c4bd208fba15a10ccc6acab83f49a" failed: exit status 1

I was under the impression that GCP supports .NET Core **2.1** containers by default, so I haven't included a *Dockerfile*.

I'm trying to deploy to the **flexible** environment, here's my `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
```

Do I need to create a custom Docker container? Or is there some other way to get support for .NET Core 2.1 in Google Cloud Shell?

**Edit:** For now I've installed Google Cloud Tools to run `gcloud app deploy` in a shell locally after running `dotnet publish`.

Comment: Does it publish locally?

Comment: Yes, it works fine locally, so the container works as expected. But I can't build the app through the Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it - indeed, Cloud Shell supports .NET Core 2.0 only. I've raised that with the right engineers so Cloud Shell image is updated to support .NET Core 2.1.

In the meantime:

1. Create a docker file based off of this image:
   **gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:2.1**
2. Try using **[gcloud builds submit](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit)** to build an image. When you run **[gcloud builds submit](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit)** for the first time, it will ask to enable **Cloud Build API**. Approve that. This will not use local (i. e. CloudShell's) **docker build** command but rather submit your artifacts to be built by [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/) and pushed to container registry.
3. Deploy to AppEngine Flex with **[gcloud app deploy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy)**, specifying **--image-url** with the image address from container registry as you built it in previous step.

Comment: Google Cloud Shell now supports .NET Core 2.1, you should be able to build ASP.NET Core 2.1 code on Google Cloud Shell.

Comment: What about 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Microsoft switch from aspnetcore to dotnet on the dotnet core image.
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/